# Problem binding to port 80: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6 with certbot certonly

Tags: ssl-certificate, glassfish, centos7, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm trying to update an SSL certificate with the command certbot certonly But I get this error:

```
Problem binding to port 80: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6.
```

running netstat -plunt shows that port 80 is been used by 'Glassfish'.
When i stop glassfish,  I have the following error: "Challenge failed for domain xxxxxxxx.net"

how could i get an ssl certificate with cerbot certonly for a website hosting on Glassfish.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbe0D.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nojTm.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the exact command that you are using for updating the certificates? Try using this command.

```
certbot renew
```

Read about it more [here](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html?highlight=renew#renewing-certificates).